# Keras error: Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got 1816

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I was trying to do a image classifier using python and Keras, but I encountered the folowing error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that 
you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected 
to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1816 arrays:
```

I tried changing x_train into a numpy array but still got an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_13_input to have 4 
dimensions, but got array with shape (1816, 1)
```

this is a part of my code:

```
def read_and_process_image(imagesTrain):

    x_train = []
    y_train = []

    for trImage in imagesTrain:
        x_train.append(cv2.imread(trImage, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR))

        if 'A' in trImage:
            y_train.append(0)
        elif 'B' in trImage:
            y_train.append(1)


    return x_train, y_train


x_train, y_train = read_and_process_image(train_imgs)


modelo.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=50,epochs=7,verbose=1)
```

I didn´t show the whole code so that it doesn´t fill the whole window but does someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: expecting 'y_train' to have 4 dimensions but it has 2. you are just appending zeros and ones.

Answer (score 0):

It expected the x_train with 4 dimensions, which are (number of images, width, height, nchannels)

```
for trImage in imagesTrain:
    x_train.append(np.array(cv2.imread(trImage, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)))

    if 'A' in trImage:
        y_train.append(0)
    elif 'B' in trImage:
        y_train.append(1)


return np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
```